# How to figure out why a task failed in Jetpack WorkManager?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager, crashlytics-android

I have integrated Jetpack WorkManager into my application and for some reason the Worker is failing because of an exception. When this happens locally in my development environment, that fine. I can just see in logcat what is going wrong.

But when I deploy my app to a lot of mobile devices I want to retrieve the full Exception with stacktrace so that I can send it to Crashlytics for example. At the moment I can only observe the Worker and that will give me a FAILED status. But no additional information.

Any idea how to get additional information about FAILED workers?

Comment: What kind of Worker are you using (CoroutineWorker, ListenableWorker, Worker)?

Can you post a code snippets of your worker?